# Getting first word after a special character in a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have some strings like this:

```
s='@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.'
t='heyyyyy@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
m='heyyyyy @VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
u=''
f='@United...'
h='@United@VirginAmerica'
```

I want to take out the word after @ in a data frame and delete this word from its data frame.
now I use this one for taking out the first word after @ but the result is not correct in all strings.

```
s.split(' ', 1)[0]==>correct==>VirginAmerica
t.split(' ', 1)[0]==>wrong==>heyyyyy@VirginAmerica==>'VirginAmerica' is correct 
m.split(' ', 1)[0]==>correct==>VirginAmerica
u.split(' ', 1)[0]==>correct==>''
f.split(' ', 1)[0]==>wrong==>@United...==>'United' is correct
h.split(' ', 1)[0]==>wrong==>@United@VirginAmerica==>I just want the first one
```

and for removing the word after @ and writing the whole string without @ and the word, I will receive these:

```
s.split(' ', 1)[1]==>correct==>it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.
t.split(' ', 1)[1]==>wrong==>@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?==>'heyyyyy , am I dreaming?' is correct 
m.split(' ', 1)[1]==>wrong==>@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?==>VirginAmerica==>'heyyyyy , am I dreaming?' is correct
u.split(' ', 1)[1]==>wrong==>IndexError: list index out of range==> ''is correct
f.split(' ', 1)[1]==>wrong==>IndexError: list index out of range==>'...' is correct
h.split(' ', 1)[1]==>wrong==>IndexError: list index out of range==>'@VirginAmerica' is correct
```

could you please help me with this problem? it would be better to not use any library. but if it is the only choice, it is ok.

Thanks

Comment: What happens to the `@` symbol? None of the examples work for me (except `u`).

Comment: it will be deleted

Comment: But the `@` is not deleted in your examples, so they are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code with tests

```
import re

s='@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.'
t='heyyyyy@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
m='heyyyyy @VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
u=''
f='@United...'
h='@United@VirginAmerica'

def find_match(str):
  res = re.search('@(\w+)', str)
  if not res:
    return ''
  return res.group(1)

def sub_match(str):
  return re.sub('^[^@]*@\w+', '', str)

assert find_match(s) == 'VirginAmerica'
assert find_match(t) == 'VirginAmerica'
assert find_match(m) == 'VirginAmerica'
assert find_match(u) == ''
assert find_match(f) == 'United'
assert find_match(h) == 'United'

assert sub_match(s) == ' it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.'
assert sub_match(t) == ' , am I dreaming?'
assert sub_match(m) == ' , am I dreaming?'
assert sub_match(u) == ''
assert sub_match(f) == '...'
assert sub_match(h) == '@VirginAmerica'
```

### find_match(str)

The core idea is to use regexp.

We are looking for the first word which starts with `@` sign. It's easy to describe with next regexp

=> `@\w+`

where `@` means match the exact character and `\w+` match 1 or more word characters[(docs explanation for this)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-31).

And also we use `()` to pick the resulting group, as we interested in a word without `@` we wrap `\w+` only

=> `@(\w+)`

### sub_match(str)

It uses the same idea for regexp but it's a little bit tricker because of the case with the first match of `@` character.

For that purposes first, we match all chars which are not `@` -> `[^@]*` regexp part, and then we use the same regexp which we used in `find_match(str)` but without group as we just need to replace the whole thing with `@`.

**PS**
Link to launch the code in web  https://repl.it/repls/SinfulWhichSynergy
Here you can test [your python regexps and practice with](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%5B%5E%40%5D*%40%5Cw%2B&test_string=%40VirginAmerica%20it%20was%20amazing%2C%20and%20arrived%20an%20hour%20early.%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I do the second part of my question? writing out the string without @first_word

Comment: @CFD I extended the answer to contain the second part of your question 

Answer (score 2):

Another implementation using regex, this gets the word following `@` from the string.

```
import re

s='@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.'
t='heyyyyy@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
m='heyyyyy @VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
u=''
f='@United...'
h='@United@VirginAmerica'

for text in [s, t, m, u, f, h]:
    print(re.findall(r'@(\w+)', text))
```

this prints

```
['VirginAmerica ']
['VirginAmerica ']
['VirginAmerica ']
[]
['United']
['United', 'VirginAmerica']
```

Also it's good to note, [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is a  standard python library so you are not using anything that isn't included with python already.

If you don't want to use regex you can use split still but something like this will result in the same as the above:

```
s='@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.'
t='heyyyyy@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
m='heyyyyy @VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?'
u=''
f='@United...'
h='@United@VirginAmerica'

for text in [s, t, m, u, f, h]:
    _, *words = text.split('@')
    print([words.split()[0] for word in words])
```

**Edit**

As per your comment, to get the first occurence of the word following `@` for example the first word `'united'` in `h` just use list slicing *(just be sure to make sure there is at least one word that matches the regex otherwise use a try except block)*

```
h='@United@VirginAmerica'
re.sub(r'@(\w+)' h)[0]
#United
```

To get the word without the first occurence of the @word use [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) I also included a space and question mark after it to remove a space so it looks right when printed. *(if you want it to print all of the occurences removed just remove `count` from this method)*

```
s='@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.'
re.sub(r'@(\w+) ?', '', s, count=1)
#it was amazing, and arrived an hour early.
```

I have everything I did in a repl.it [give it a try](https://repl.it/repls/PrestigiousPersonalToolbox)

Comment: I just noticed I did it wrong the first time, he was looking for the words not the sentences without them

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I get just the first word after @? for example for 'h' , I dont want to have both words.

Moreover, do you know how to do the second part which I mentioned? removing @first_word from the string and writing the remainning part of string

Answer (score 0):

This answer just uses simple python functions, and tries not to be 'pythonic' since this can be confusing for beginners.

Basically it looks for an `@` in the sentence with `sentence.find('@')`, which returns the location index of the first occurrence of '@', or `-1`.  One of the things not mentioned in the OP's question, is what constitutes an "@word" - more importantly *where does it stop*.  I added the `WORD_END` constant to hold all the letters that denote the end of a word.  So the function finds an "@word" from the first `@` and up to the first character in `WORD_END`.

One other point to note, is that there is no test case where there is no '@' in the sentence.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

TESTS=['@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early',
        'heyyyyy@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?',
        'heyyyyy @VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?',
        '',
        '@United...',
        '@United@VirginAmerica',
        'no-at-word' ]

def removeMarkedWords(sentence):
    # A word ends with
    WORD_END=' \t\r\n,.;:<>?/+!@#$%^&*()|\}][{\"\'='
    result = ''

    # is there an @word?
    at_location = sentence.find('@')
    if ( at_location == -1 ):
        result = sentence
    else:
        while ( at_location != -1 ):
            if ( at_location > 0 ):
                result += sentence[0:at_location]  # keep the sentence prefix (before the '@')
                sentence = sentence[at_location:]  # remove the prefix
            else:
                # The sentence begins '@something...'
                # Find the end of the @word by finding the first non-word letter
                index = 1
                while ( index < len(sentence) and sentence[index] not in WORD_END ):
                    index += 1
                # trim off the @word (and throw it away)
                sentence = sentence[index:]
                #print( "DEBUG sentence = [" + sentence + "]" )
            # is there another @word?
            at_location = sentence.find('@')
            if ( at_location == -1 ):
                result += sentence  # no more @words, just keep the tail
    return result


for test in TESTS:
    print( "[%s]->[%s]" % ( test, removeMarkedWords( test ) ) )
```

Giving the result:

```
[@VirginAmerica it was amazing, and arrived an hour early]->[ it was amazing, and arrived an hour early]
[heyyyyy@VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?]->[heyyyyy , am I dreaming?]
[heyyyyy @VirginAmerica , am I dreaming?]->[heyyyyy  , am I dreaming?]
[]->[]
[@United...]->[...]
[@United@VirginAmerica]->[]
[no-at-word]->[no-at-word]
```